# I cant get studio code to install dotenv with pip install. Error cant find module, how do I fix it please?

Tags: python, visual-studio

PS C:\Users\gwill\OneDrive\Documents\new luno\Luno10> pip install dotenv
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\gwill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Users\gwill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe" install dotenv': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd recommend you to [create a virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments), activate it and try again. `pip` is going to be available on the virtual environment you create.

Comment: Thanks I am a beginner, will you please provide more information about it please?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `pip install python-dotenv`.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR;

In the project folder type this step by step depending on the platform (Linux/macOS or Windows):

| Command-Line Linux/macOS | Command-Line Windows | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `python3 -m venv .venv` | `python -m venv .venv` | Creates the virtual env (in this case the `.venv` folder) |
| `. ./.venv/bin/activate` (bash/zsh) `. ./.venv/bin/activate.fish` (fish shell) | `.venv\Scripts\activate.bat` (cmd.exe) `.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1` (Powershell) | Activates it |
| `pip install dotenv` | `pip install dotenv` | Installs a 3rd party package (in this case `dotenv`) |
| `python script.py` | `python script.py` | Runs the script (in this case `script.py`) |
| `deactivate` | `deactivate` | Deactivates it later |

## What is a Virtual Environment?

By default, Python installs 3rd-party packages on the System Site Directories. And in most cases, this even requires admin privileges like `sudo` (Linux/macOS) or `Run as Administrator` (Windows).

The System Site Directories is the default environment for the installed Python. It's global for all the projects being worked on on the same system.

So, installing the requirements/3rd-party packages from each project on the System Site Directories is going to pollute it. And worse, it could clash versions of the same module dependency between different projects. And could make projects completely unrunnable.

That's why Virtual Environments exist in the first place. The Virtual Environment is a completely separate Site Directories from the System Site Directories and is (should be) exclusive to the project being developed at the moment. The project itself is going to be totally isolated from other Virtual Environments. And even the Python binaries are going to be copied/sym-linked into the Virtual Environment.

## Creating Virtual Environments

**Adapted from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments):**

Since Python 3.3 it's possible to create a Virtual Environment with the standard [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) module that comes preinstalled with Python already (Before, the standard way was to use the [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) package).

The creation of Virtual Environments is done by executing the command `venv`:

**Linux/macOS**

```
python3 -m venv .venv
```

**Windows**

```
python -m venv .venv
```

Running this command creates:

1. The target directory (`.venv` in this case);
2. The `.venv/bin` folder (or `.venv\Scripts` on Windows) containing a copy/sym-link of the Python binary/binaries;
3. The Virtual Site Directories (initially empty): `.venv/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` folder (on Windows, this is `.venv\Lib\site-packages`).

## Activating a Virtual Environment

> Once a virtual environment has been created, it can be “activated” using a script in the virtual environment’s binary directory. The invocation of the script is platform-specific:

| Platform | Shell | Command to activate the Virtual Environment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| POSIX | bash/zsh | `source .venv/bin/activate` |
|  | fish | `source <venv>/bin/activate.fish` |
|  | csh/tcsh | `source <venv>/bin/activate.csh` |
|  | PowerShell Core | `.venv/bin/Activate.ps1` |
| Windows | cmd.exe | `.venv\Scripts\activate.bat` |
|  | PowerShell | `.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1` |

As soon as the Virtual Environment is active, every install with `pip` is going to install on the Virtual Environment, safe from every other Virtual Environment.

## Deactivate a Virtual Environment

> You can deactivate a virtual environment by typing `deactivate` in your shell.