# Import "faker" could not be resolved (PylancereportMissingImports)

Tags: python, django, pip, faker

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

#FAKE POP SCRIPT
import random
from first_app.models import Topic, AccessRecord, Webpage
from faker import Faker

fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Market', 'News', 'Games']

def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name = random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t
def populate(N=5):

    for entry in range(N):
        #Get the topic for the entry
        top = add_topic()
    
        #Create the fake data for that entry
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()
    
        #Create the new webpage entry
        webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic = top,url = fake_url, name = fake_name)[0]
    
        #Create a fake access record for that webpage
        acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name = webpg, date = fake_date)[0]
    
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            print("populating script!")
            populate(20)
            print("populating complete!")
```

The code executes but does nothing. I've already try uninstall faker and install it again, install older versions, I tried to install with pip and anaconda as well but none of these worked. I would appretiate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation of `if __name__ == '__main__':` is wrong. The right way is outside the `populate` function like the following:

```py
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

#FAKE POP SCRIPT
import random
from first_app.models import Topic, AccessRecord, Webpage
from faker import Faker

fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Market', 'News', 'Games']

def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name = random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t
def populate(N=5):

    for entry in range(N):
        #Get the topic for the entry
        top = add_topic()
    
        #Create the fake data for that entry
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()
    
        #Create the new webpage entry
        webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic = top,url = fake_url, name = fake_name)[0]
    
        #Create a fake access record for that webpage
        acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name = webpg, date = fake_date)[0]
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("populating script!")
    populate(20)
    print("populating complete!")
```

Testing with [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it works:

```py
from faker import Faker

fakegen = Faker()

def populate(N=5):
    for _ in range(N):
        #Create the fake data for that entry
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()
        print(fake_url, fake_date, fake_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("populating script!")
    populate(20)
    print("populating complete!")
```

**The output**

```
populating script!
https://www.jackson-allen.com/ 1987-05-26 Rogers, Adams and Keith
https://jefferson-smith.com/ 1976-01-05 Murphy-Smith
https://swanson-evans.info/ 1986-02-10 Martin-Fields
http://www.fleming-miller.com/ 2010-06-18 Tanner-Frost
https://higgins.net/ 2008-11-20 Mccoy-Jones
http://www.cunningham.net/ 2017-02-10 Kramer-Mccall
http://wright-mills.com/ 1973-08-14 Moran, Humphrey and Spears
https://diaz.com/ 2017-05-16 Thomas Ltd
http://klein-flores.com/ 1988-12-18 Gentry Group
http://www.potts.com/ 1986-01-29 King-Moore
https://perez.biz/ 1998-09-09 Robinson, Fowler and Callahan
https://khan.com/ 2016-06-17 Wells-Mcdonald
https://manning-garcia.com/ 2011-04-28 Jenkins, Crawford and Garcia
https://foster.com/ 2004-09-26 Rodriguez Ltd
https://www.wright.com/ 1987-10-06 Velasquez Group
http://www.davis.net/ 1985-07-28 Armstrong, Wood and Grant
http://www.blevins.biz/ 1984-03-10 Ross LLC
http://www.mcintyre.biz/ 1971-11-23 Daugherty-Jackson
http://thompson.com/ 1980-07-15 Payne, Powers and Wilson
https://www.thomas-mason.com/ 2002-08-09 Pacheco, Palmer and Hernandez
populating complete!
```

Comment: Oh thanks, that solved it... But i don't understand it. There is still that error that says: ,,Import "faker" could not be resolved..."

Comment: [You can try creating a virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72765863/2828341), activating it and then installing faker with `pip install faker`. A virtual environment is completely separated from the installed system packages so the chances of conflicts are minimum.

Comment: Yeah, I do it all from the virtual environment. Just don't know why the error is still showing up. But it works fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like an IDE problem to me because the script runs fine. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: Did you change any Pylance configuration in User Settings? Would you please send me the project folder structure? Maybe it's not in the "standard" way Pylance detects sources.

Comment: I don't know if I can send you the whole folder but i have it like this:
first_project -- first_app, first_project, db.sqlite, manage.py, populate_first_app.py (The script with faker)

Comment: Sorry, I mean just how the folders are structured, not the files themselves. Something like this would do: `project`, `project/lib`, `project/lib/src`, `project/lib/scripts`, `project/lib/data`

Comment: Sorry for my absence. It's like this: `first_project`, `first_app`, `first_project`, `db.sqlite3`, `manage.py`, `populate_first_app.py`. In the `first_app` are classic things like methods.py, views.py etc. and `first_project` there are things like settings.py, urls.py etc.